# find boot-up script on any Linux/Unix installation

Tags: linux, boot, unix

I need to run a program on boot-up and install the corresponding code into the system startup-script.

Unfortunately, not all are using the same system:

- I checked Debian and CentOS and they use `/etc/rc.local` (probably also RedHat and Ubuntu)
- I checked SuSE and it uses `/etc/init.d/boot.local`
- Other distributions (Slackware, Gentoo, etc.) may use something else
- non-Linux Unixes like FreeBSD, MacOSX, OpenBSD, etc. may also use something else

I cannot try out all derivates, is there any documentation that sums up the various boot-up concepts? Also what will SystemD use? Is SuSE the only one that does not use /etc/rc.local or are there others?

Is there some "best-practice" common solution for that problem? (i.e. a script/program that checks all possibilities and returns the correct location of the startup-script)

Answer (score 0):

[crontab](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/crontab.html) should be available for all these systems.

The documentation of [advanced crontab](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/CronHowto#Advanced_Crontab) provides information about special strings such as reboot (@reboot), giving you the possibility to run your program on every boot-up.

Comment: That does not work because @reboot is a recent feature that is not supported by all distributions, also it seems quite buggy as well, see for example http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/109804/crontabs-reboot-only-works-for-root which lists a whole number of bugs in recent versions of a distribution.